# For android device how to check wifi status when there is web authentication needed for open wifi connection

Tags: android, wifi, connectivity

I have application which makes check of network connectivity before making any server request. I used connectivity manger to check network state. When i am connecting to wifi which is open network but it needs authentication credential to be entered from browser. Even if i have not enter wifi credential, connectivity manager returns me true, showing internet is connected. But it will not allow me to browse. Can anyone tell me how to handle this case.

```
public static boolean getWifiEnabled(Context context) {
        boolean result = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null
                && (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
            if (activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                result = true;
                activeNetwork.getDetailedState();
            } else {
            }
        } else {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?